# Python: populate a list with variable names?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Just say I have many variables with name sequence `var1`, `var2`, `varn`?...  e.g.:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
var3 = 3
var4 = 4
```

I would like to populate a list with these variable names. I tried to do it like this but it didn't work:

```
def namestr(obj, namespace):
    return [name for name in namespace if namespace[name] is obj]
variables = []
for i in range(1,5):
    variables.append(namestr(vars()['semplus' + str(i)], globals()))
```

does anyone know how to do such a thing?
the result should be like:

```
 [var1, var2, var3, var4]
```

Comment: I would intervene after the first sentence and question why you have thusly named variables at all?! Why not a list instead?

Comment: Sounds like a dict is more appropriate to use here.

Comment: You should be using a data structure as a dictionary instead of variables for this. But just for the record, the. `locals()` call will return what you expect as `namespace` in your example.

Comment: @deceze what's wrong with named variables?

Comment: Exactly the problem you're currently coming up against: you can't handle them in aggregate, and the names don't really add anything of value. `var[1]`, `var[2]` would be virtually the same, but is easily handleable as a whole as well.

Comment: We, or at least I, don't like to see "does't work".  I want to know what happened.  Error?  unexpect values?  WIth some adjustment, you code does run, producing a list of list of strings.  But I don't see the point of getting strings.  In python there's a difference between a `variable` and its `name`, a string.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to do this with a dictionary:

```py
In [1]: d = {}                                                                                        

In [2]: for i in range(1,5): 
   ...:     d[f"var{i}"] = i 
   ...:                                                                                               

In [3]: d["var1"]                                                                                     
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: d.keys()                                                                                      
Out[4]: dict_keys(['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'])
```

Answer (score 0):

With your `var#` definitions, in a workspace that I've been using for other tests:

```
In [330]: def namestr(obj, namespace):
     ...:     return [name for name in namespace if namespace[name] is obj]
     ...: variables = []
     ...: for i in range(1,5):
     ...:     variables.append(namestr(vars()['var' + str(i)], globals()))
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [331]: variables
Out[331]: [['i', 'var1'], ['i', 'j', 'var2'], ['dim', 'i', 'var3'], ['i', 'var4']]
```

What's going on here?  `var2` has a value 2.  So does `j` from prior use.  And `i` is the current iteration variable.

```
In [332]: var1
Out[332]: 1
In [333]: var3
Out[333]: 3
In [334]: dim             # a prior use of this variable
Out[334]: 3
In [335]: i
Out[335]: 4
In [336]: j
Out[336]: 2
```

So you are getting names of variables with values corresponding to the respective `var1`, `var2` etc. variables.